# Grails: flash message and errors

Tags: grails, flash-message

I cant display the validation errors

```
def saveTable() {
    def tableInstance = new Table(params)
    if (!tableInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        tableInstance.errors.each {
            flash.message = it //<---- this part
        }
        redirect(action: "listTable")
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'table.label', default: 'Table'), tableInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "listTable")
```

The flash message doesnt seem to show the errors

I tried if the errors are shown with `println it` and there are errors too

I tested it with a normal string `flash.message = "a"` and it works with my script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        (function() {   
            <g:if test='${flash.message}'>
            $('document').ready(function(){
                $.gritter.add({
                    title: '',
                    text: '${flash.message}',
                    image: '',
                    sticky: false,
                    time: ''            
                });
                return false;
            });
            </g:if>
        })();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This code resets the  flash.message in each loop iteration.

```
    tableInstance.errors.each {
        flash.message = it //<---- this part
    }
```

Try to combine the errors like this for example

```
    tableInstance.errors.each {
        flash.message += it + "<br>"
    }
```

Comment: it still doesnt work. I may need to parse the errors into string

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you mean:

```
tableInstance.errors.allErrors.each {
    flash.message = it;
}
```

You might find this useful: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html

Also, assigning the flash message in this loop will overwrite it if there are multiple errors. Maybe you want to concatenate them somehow?

Comment: it still doesnt work. I may need to parse the errors into string